How do I tell VS Code NOT to open a new instance if already opened?
In order to resolve VSCode complains that resolving my environment takes too long,
I want to open VS Code from my .bashrc file, like this:
code

How do I tell VS Code NOT to open a new instance every time I run .bashrc? That is, I want multiple command prompts, but only one VS Code.

You can write a bash wrapper that checks if vs code is already running, and only runs it if there is no code process according to ps

Thanks, this works: if ! pgrep -x "code" > /dev/null then code fi

@Danijel you should add that as an answer and accept it later if you don't get a better one.

btw: Instead of if ! pgrep -x "code" > /dev/null then code fi you can write pgrep -x "code" > /dev/null || code

Thanks Wiimm, but that seems less readable.

In case you are having problems as in VSCode complains that resolving my environment takes too long, and don't feel like starting VS Code from the command line, add this to your .bashrc:
### Start VS Code unless it is already running
if ! pgrep -x "code" > /dev/null
then
code
fi
###

